# How can I run a codeblock project by using command line

Tags: c++, command-line, codeblocks

I am doing some project using c++ on codeblock now.

I am trying to put my project on to jenkins, so I need to write some command line to build it automatically.

I surveyed some information on this web http://www.codeblocks.org/docs/main_codeblocks_en3.html

and tried something like "codeblocks.exe --no-splash-screen --built main.cbp --target='Debug'  "

but it didn't work

Could someone tell me where I did wrong?

I really appreciate that! Thanks!

Comment: _" tried something like..."_ please show the exact command; _"but it didn't work"_ and the output you got.  Making us guess the command AND the output is not going to get you very far.

Comment: sorry I didn't describe clearly
I tried C:\Users\Jeff\Desktop\oop\test>codeblocks.exe /na /nd --no-splash-screen --built test.cbp --target='Debug'
and the output said that codeblock.exe is not a internal/external command

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by setting windows environment path

Comment: What path did you add?

Comment: Computer->Properties->Advanced system settings->Advanced->Environment Variables, and add the codeblock.exe path that you installed as a new system path